# TypeError: jQuery.smoothScroll is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

this functions is working fine on my another page but when i call the same function from another page it gives an error (TypeError: jQuery.smoothScroll is not a function
        jQuery.smoothScroll({ speed: 1000 }, parseInt(offset+290));) please help..!!)

```
    if(fav_page == 'favorite'){
                                        scroll_to_middle("#fav_marker_"+ locations[i][4]);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        scroll_to_middle("#loc_marker_"+ locations[i][4]);  
                                    }


function scroll_to_middle(favId)
        {
                  var el = jQuery(favId);
                  var elOffset = el.offset().top;
                  var elHeight = el.height();
                  var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
                  var offset;

                  if (elHeight < windowHeight) {
                    offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2));
                  }
                  else {
                    offset = elOffset;
                  }
                  if(jQuery( window ).width() <= 1366)
                  {
                      jQuery.smoothScroll({ speed: 1000 }, parseInt(offset+290));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      jQuery.smoothScroll({ speed: 1000 }, parseInt(offset+50));
                  }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Make sure the base library/plugin is exist on that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other page includes js from this plugin https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll

You can put

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll/master/jquery.smooth-scroll.js"></script>
```

somewhere above your code to make it work